# problem in pushing notification in multi specific times for each record

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am working on home pharmacy app which has multi members for every single user, that's mean (one app for all family members) so I have a user table and member table and drugs table and member_drugs table.

### member table have columns:

`id`, `user_id`, `name`, `age`, ...etc...

### member_drugs table has columns:

`id`, `member_id`, `drug_id`, `drug dose`, `drug dose repetition` (i.e how many hours between the first dose and the after doses in a single day - maybe 6 hours), `first time dose`, and etc...

now I need to push notifications for every dose reminder (all repetitions in its specific time).

### for example:

drug x for member y and the drug dose repetition is 3 hours and the first time for the drug is 12 am, so: I need to push notification in:
1- the first time in: `12 am`.
and the repetitions in:

2- `3 am`.

3- `6 am`.

4- `9 am`.

5- .... etc..

my problem that the notification comes only for the first time.

I am tried in this code but it's not working. I don't know what I missed

### this is my notification service method:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {

        Date date = new Date();
        toda = dateFormat.format(date);
        today = dateFormat.parse(toda, new ParsePosition(0));

        java.util.Date date1 = new java.util.Date();
        String current = sdf.format(date1);

        Date now1 = sdf.parse(current, new ParsePosition(0));
        String now = sdf.format(now1);
        arrayList1 = setTimeAlarm();
        if (arrayList1 != null) {
            if (arrayList1.size() > 0) {
                for (DrugAlert d : arrayList1) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "heeeeeeeeeeeeer");

                    String start = d.get_start_date();
                    Date d1 = dateFormat.parse(start, new ParsePosition(0));
                    String end = d.get_end_date();
                    Date d2 = dateFormat.parse(end, new ParsePosition(0));
                    String firstTime = d.getAlert_time();
                    Date t1 = sdf.parse(firstTime, new ParsePosition(0));
                    String t = sdf.format(t1);
                    int repeat = d.getDose_r();

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // creates calendar
                    cal.setTime(t1); // sets calendar time/date

                    if ((d2.after(today) || d2.equals(today)) && (d1.equals(today) || today.after(d1))) {
                            for (int i = repeat; i<=24; i = i +repeat){
                               // i = repeat;
                                cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,i); // adds one hour if repeat == 1
                                cal.getTime(); // returns new date object, one hour in the future
                                Date repDose1 = cal.getTime();
                                String repDose = sdf.format(repDose1);
                                if (t.equals(now) || repDose.equals(now) ) {
                                    memName = d.getMember_name();
                                    drugName = d.getDrug_name();
                                    courseId = d.get__id();
                                    dose = d.getDose_q();
                                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onHandleIntent, started handling a notification event");
                                    try {
                                        processStartNotification();
                                        NOTIFICATION_ID = NOTIFICATION_ID +1;
                                        String action = intent.getAction();
                                        if (ACTION_START.equals(action)) {
                                            processStartNotification();
                                        }
                                    } finally {
                                        WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

                                    }
                                }
                            }



                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix by the following code:

```js
 @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {

        Date date = new Date();
        toda = dateFormat.format(date);
        today = dateFormat.parse(toda, new ParsePosition(0));

        java.util.Date date1 = new java.util.Date();
        String current = sdf.format(date1);

        Date now1 = sdf.parse(current, new ParsePosition(0));
        String now = sdf.format(now1);
        arrayList1 = setTimeAlarm();
        if (arrayList1 != null) {
            if (arrayList1.size() > 0) {
                for (DrugAlert d : arrayList1) {
                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "heeeeeeeeeeeeer");

                    String start = d.get_start_date();
                    Date d1 = dateFormat.parse(start, new ParsePosition(0));
                    String end = d.get_end_date();
                    Date d2 = dateFormat.parse(end, new ParsePosition(0));
                    String firstTime = d.getAlert_time();
                    Date t1 = sdf.parse(firstTime, new ParsePosition(0));
                    String t = sdf.format(t1);
                    int repeat = d.getDose_r();
                    
                    if ((d2.after(today) || d2.equals(today)) && (d1.equals(today) || today.after(d1))) {
                          //  for (int i = repeat; i<=24; i = i +repeat){
                        int f = repeat;
                        while (f <= 24){
                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // creates calendar
                            cal.setTime(t1); // sets calendar time/date
                            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, f);// adds one hour if repeat == 1
                            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                                cal.getTime(); // returns new date object, one hour in the future
                                Date repDose1 = cal.getTime();
                                String repDose = sdf.format(repDose1);
                                if (t.equals(now) || repDose.equals(now)) {

                                    memName = d.getMember_name();
                                    drugName = d.getDrug_name();
                                    courseId = d.get__id();
                                    dose = d.getDose_q();
                                    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onHandleIntent, started handling a notification event");
                                    try {
                                        processStartNotification();
                                        NOTIFICATION_ID = NOTIFICATION_ID +1;
                                        String action = intent.getAction();
                                        if (ACTION_START.equals(action)) {
                                            processStartNotification();
                                        }
                                    } finally {
                                        WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

                                    }
                                }
                                f = f + repeat;
                                if(f == 4){
                                    int x=1;
                                    int y=x+2;
                                }
                            }



                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
```